# Could not load requested class : oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Tags: java, database, oracle, jpa

I've added the jars in the Build path

[image: Bluild Path JARS of ojdbc]

Here are the Persistence Units from xml file

```
<persistence-unit name="my-persistence-unit">
</persistence-unit>
<persistence-unit name="StudentManagement"

    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.model.StudentModel</class>
    <properties>
        <!-- enable warnings for debugging -->
        <property name="openjpa.Log"
            value="DefaultLevel=TRACE, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE" />

        <!-- connection properties -->

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="system" />

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
            value="system" />

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
            value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />

        <property
            name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
            value="create" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Here is my Dao Implementation class

```
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("StudentManagement");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerfactory.createEntityManager();

    EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();

    entityManager.persist(obj);


    transaction.commit();
    entityManager.close();
    entityManagerfactory.close();
```

Anything left to do as far as I know these were the only thing required to use JPA with Oracle DB

Comment: Why did you add two versions of the same JDBC driver to the CLASSPATH?

Comment: Tried adding one by one didn't work, so loaded both

Comment: Do you try to execute the code in place (inside Eclipse, starting the Tomcat inside Eclipse), or did you deploy the code first to an external Tomcat? When you added the JARs to the Buildpath in Eclipse, it is the *Build CLASSPATH*. It is used to create the *Execution CLASSPATH* when you click on "Run As -> Java Application". But when executing on a server, external JARs had to be provided by that environment.

Comment: I ran my code in place (inside Eclipse, starting the Tomcat inside Eclipse) Selecting the project --> Runa s --> Run on Server

Comment: Why you use Eclipse to pull in Oracle drivers when you are already using maven? Then, decide if you want to use this lib as provided (and add it to the server) or if you want to package it with your app.